# Getting horizontal lines for summaries in ggplot with stat_summary_bin

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to take a ggplot scatterplot and overlay on top of it the mean of the y-variable within evenly-spaced bins on the x-axis.

So far what I have is this:

```
library(tidyverse)
data(midwest)
ggplot(arrange(midwest,percollege),aes(x=percollege,y=percbelowpoverty))+
    geom_point()+ 
    stat_summary_bin(aes(x=percollege,y=percbelowpoverty),
        bins=10,fun.y='mean',geom='point',col='red')
```

Which produces
[image]

which is basically perfect except instead of red points I would like horizontal red lines that extend from the beginning of the bin to the end of the bin.

I can sort of mimic what I want with

```
library(tidyverse)
data(midwest)
ggplot(arrange(midwest,percollege),aes(x=percollege,y=percbelowpoverty))+
    geom_point()+ 
    stat_summary_bin(aes(x=percollege,y=percbelowpoverty),
        bins=10,fun.y='mean',geom='point',col='red',shape="-",size=50)
```

which gives

[image]

Which is kinda what I want, except

1. I have to manually set the size every time I make a new graph like this
2. Uh, ew.

Another approach I've tried is with `geom='bar',fill=NA`, which seems promising if I can somehow get it to only show the top bar without the sides or bottom of the bar.

Any tips for this? I've had little luck with setting the geom to `pointrange` or `linerange` or `line` (the first two I've yet to get to work, and the last just connects each point with non-horizontal lines). Kind of surprised this isn't default behavior for `stat_summary_bin` to be honest!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work. I think the `rownames_to_column` line may not be necessary, and the `modify_if` argument is necessary because the `cut` function produces strings rather than than numeric values.

```
midwest_sum <- midwest %>%
  mutate(coll_bins = cut(percollege, breaks = 10)) %>%
  group_by(coll_bins) %>%
  summarise(bin_mean = mean(percbelowpoverty)) %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "bin_num") %>%
  tidyr::extract(coll_bins, c("min", "max"), "\\((.*),(.*)]") %>%
  modify_if(is.character, as.numeric)


ggplot()+
    geom_point(data = midwest, aes(x=percollege,y=percbelowpoverty)) +
    geom_errorbarh(data = midwest_sum, aes(xmin = min, xmax = max, y = bin_mean), 
                   col = "red", size = 1)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't often call this desired default behaviour; leaving out the sides of the bins necessarily makes it confusing where the bin boundaries actually are for points far above or below the bin means.

Anyway, here's a first attempt. We can calculate the bin boundaries based on some input parameter and then use `geom_segment` to draw them on the graph. `geom_segment` needs start and end coordinates, so `bin_boundaries` calculates the means of the y variable and the bounds of the bins for the x variable, and returns a call to `geom_segment`. This means we can simply add the output of our function to our `ggplot` call and it works as expected. Note the use of passing through `...` so we can still use the `geom` parameters.

You can probably modify to use other bin width and dodge parameters instead of calculating from the bounds of your x variable, haven't thought too carefully about that. Note that the lines look different from your use of `stat_summary_bin` because they are centered differently and so use different points in each calculation. You might also consider a version that uses `geom_step` which would connect the ends of each horizontal line.

```r
library(tidyverse)
bin_boundaries <- function(tbl, n_bins, x_var, y_var, ...) {
  x_var <- enquo(x_var)
  y_var <- enquo(y_var)
  bin_bounds <-  seq(
    from = min(pull(tbl, !!x_var)),
    to = max(pull(tbl, !!x_var)),
    length.out = n_bins + 1)
  bounds_tbl <- tbl %>%
    mutate(bin_group = ntile(!!x_var, n_bins)) %>%
    group_by(bin_group) %>%
    summarise(!!y_var := mean(!!y_var)) %>%
    mutate(bin_start = bin_bounds[1:n_bins], bin_end = bin_bounds[2:(n_bins + 1)])
  geom_segment(
    data = bounds_tbl,
    mapping = aes(
      x = bin_start, y = !!y_var,
      xend = bin_end, yend = !!y_var
    ),
    ...
  )
}

ggplot(midwest) +
  geom_point(aes(x = percollege, y = percbelowpoverty)) +
  bin_boundaries(midwest, 10, percollege, percbelowpoverty, colour = "red", size = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-02-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>